# About setcontext() in C++, In what case those code under this function can be executed?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading code of one user level threading library project, one episode code is below:

```
/*This function to manage mainthread*/
static void main_thread_manager()
{
    mainThread->status = 1;
    setcontext(&mainThread->context);
    if(mainThread->exited != 1)
    {
        mainThread->finished = 1;
    }
    setcontext(&scheduler_context);
    return;
}
```

This code is to finish the mainthread used from here

```
makecontext(&mainThread->context, (void(*)(void)) main_thread_manager, 0, NULL, NULL);//(1)
```

I am a newbie on this field. I have to say this code is correct, because when I delete any line of it, the program wouldn't exit. I can't copy all my code here because it is too much.

`&scheduler_context`would lead to my scheduler function then the whole process would exit.

It seems everytime when the code run to setcontext() in the 1st code, the context would go to other place. Why there exists some code under setcontext()?

Supplement:

In fact, after looking at one answer below, I want to mention sth here.
The `makecontext` above is in the initial() function where mainthread is created. But In the create_thread() function, where I create other new thread. There is still one function like this:

```
getcontext(&mainThread->context);//(2)
```

Is that mean? when we setcontext(&mainThread->context), the program would first look for (2), if the create_thread has finished, the setcontext would jump to (1)?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737852/how-dose-makecontext-work-on-the-context-value-about-user-level-threading-lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below of [setcontext](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) will be executed if setcontext fails.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you read my supplement and give some idea?